# Securing WebHosting Shell Access

Tags: linux, ssh, permissions, web-hosting

If I provide SSH access to users who has paid webhosting service, what security measures should be applied ?

What I can think of:

- SSH keys RSA of 4096 size (shall be secure for a while)
- Apache MPM-ITK (separating each domain/subdomain) via separate user/group according to business (who paid for which service)
- Permissions to each web root (0750) recursively
- Checking for dangerous/invalid SUID/SGID binaries in $PATH
- umask (027) so new files are covered by default

Similar answer is [Securing restricted shell environments](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/9720/securing-restricted-shell-environments), but in my opinion doesn't cover the specific use-case of mine.

Answer (score 1):

**why** do you want to provide shell-access? if it is something like services-restart or defined task that might be executed via scripts, use a simple, shell-based task-manager that allows only defined actions (or better, use a tool like rundesk/jenkins to provide the same tasks to you clients via webinterface)

if you need full shell-access, well, either chroot or live with the consequences :)

regardings ssh:

- make sure your keys are pw-protected
- generate keys yourself, if you can
- forbid pw-login
- put ssh onto another port if possible
- use sudo and tight NOPASSWD - definitions, e.g restrict to `/etc/init.d/apache reload` instead of `/etc/init.d/apache2`  which would allow `stop` too

your umask 027 might break stuff, expecially if you allow fileupload via scp.